# How to monitor Kafka Consumer lag in Stackdriver?

Tags: monitoring, gcloud, kafka, google-stackdriver

I can view all the Kafka broker metrics by using the JMX exporter -> stackdriver monitoring agent and is displayed in the Stackdriver but i cant see any consumer metrics, i am particularly interested in consumer lag,   is there a way to monitor kafka consumer metrics via stackdriver?

Answer (score 0):

At this time, Stackdriver Monitoring does not monitor the kafka consumer metrics. There was a request for this feature to be added and it is being looked into; however, I cannot provide an ETA on if/when this feature will be applied.